# Currently PayFlow Pro user, how do I upgrade to the latest?

Tags: payflowpro

I just inherited code base that uses PayFlow Pro, this product seems to be out of date and we'd like to upgrade to the latest product using PayPal SDK, what is the best way to do this? What is the best migration strategy?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the SDK's here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/directory/

If you are in US and processing your transactions via Payflow, recommendation would be to continue using PayflowSDK.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it is necessary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This *barely* does that, at best.